# How to fix JSON_ERROR_UTF8

Tags: php, json

I want to get JSON but it is not working when there is a **"Ñ"**. I have a change the collation of my database to **utf8_general_ci**. The total count of the data is **2292**. When I use json_encode nothing appears but when I use echo the data appears. How can I fix this?

```
$sql = "SELECT FileAs FROM tblContacts WHERE Coordinator = '$ContactID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $ar[] = array(
           'FileAs' => $row['FileAs']
       );
    }
} 

print json_encode($ar);
```

Comment: json_encode shouldn't have any problem whatsoever with Ñ, nor any other valid unicode character, something else is going on here. what do yo get from `var_dump($ar);ob_start();var_dump($ar);echo bin2hex(ob_get_clean());` ?

Comment: @hanshenrik I got JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error or "- Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Comment: no, you did not. the var_dump code i asked you to run will give you something completely different.